# c++ to c# Conversion Queries

Tags: c#, c++, type-conversion

I am Re-Writing an C++ assembly into a c# assembly. I am facing an issue while handling pointers that refers to a particular memory address.
Ex :
int a=0;
int *b=&a;

I have done some research and found that we can make the method as unsafe and use pointers. apart from making the method as unsafe, is there any other way we can handle this in c# that is logically correct according to C++.

Also please let me know if there is any C+++ assemblies i need to keep in mind that might cause trouble while converting to c#.

Comment: More often than not, the best way to do such conversions is not just translating each construct from one language to the other, but to analize what's being achieved by each function and replicate the functionality accordingly.

Comment: I think the `c++` tag (which means native standard c++ not managed / .net) here is not correct. I think you are using `c++-cli`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For your specific snippet, you can use the `ref` keyword:

```
int a = 0;
ref int b = ref a;
```

That should behave just like C++. No need for unsafe code.